# How to calculate Area of polygon by Simpson's rule using coordinates?

Tags: python

This code uses [Simpson's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_rule), but gives the wrong area of a polygon by the formula:

[image]

```
def defineArea(xCoords, yCoords):    

    i = 0
    sum = 0
    for i in xrange(len(xCoords) - 1):         
        result = (xCoords[i] - xCoords[i+1])*(yCoords[i]+ yCoords[i+1])

        i +=1
        sum = 0.5*(sum + result)
    print "Total 2D area is: ", sum*
```

What I am doing wrong?
How do I calculate the area of polygon by Simpson's rule using  only coordinates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do `sum = 0.5*(sum + result)` inside the loop. Also, you don't need the `sum` variable at all once it's outside the loop. Just do `result = 0.5 * result` after the loop is complete, then print `result`.

You also need to switch the order of `xCoords[i]` and `xCoords[i+1]`.

Answer (score 1):

Do what "Bill the Lizard" said (sorry I can't post a comment yet), or you can do it inside the loop too:

```
sum = sum + 0.5*result
```

Also, you are doing `(xCoords[i] - xCoords[i+1])` instead of `(xCoords[i+1] - xCoords[i])`